# use different field name in cakephp form

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

is it possible to change the name of a input field in cakephp? I tried with virtual fields, but it does shows the original column name from database.

can someone help me with this?

Comment: have you tried with `$this->Form->input('dbinput', array('name'=>'mychangedname'))` ? or is not that what you want? can you be more specific?

Comment: More clarification please?

Answer (score 1):

its pretty easy.. use it like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('theField', array( 'label'=>'Change the Text')); ?>
```

instead of this:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('theField'); ?>
```

i hope this helps! :)